# Bar Code in C# not getting detected

Tags: c#, barcode, rdlc, barcode-scanner, barcode-printing

I have a report (.rdlc) file which has information from an ID card.
Now I am taking content from an excel file and filling up the id card. That card gets exported to a (.pdf) file. That's what the program does.

when I print it, the bar code is generated, but it does not get detected by the scanners.
I have checked the font size, text box size and editing stuff like that but still no luck!

To get the bar code, I made a textbox and gave it the variable name in which the number is stored. I just changed the format of the font in it to 3 of 9 (the barcode font).

What am I doing wrong? I have checked other questions, but all of them just lead me to all Bar Code generator software!

Comment: Are you sure, your barcode scanner accepts 3of9 without markers? Try to put a `*` at the start and at the end of the barcode!

Comment: yea, it does accept it.
I've tried checking it by scanning the previous years id card.

Comment: And those ID cards **don't** have markers?

Comment: No. 
But ive noticed one thing.
When I type the same number which is there in the previous years ID card, it doesn't match. I mean, the one that I type is bigger.

Comment: Try printing `*blahblah*` and `blahblah` in your 3of9 font (just e.g. from Word) and check, whether the scanner can read both

Comment: And try changing the font to something normal to see, if the text is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put asterisk '*' at start and end of a Code 39 bar code, like this: `*123*`